# Like and Send Buttons for Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook, jquery-mobile

I am using Facebook Like and Send buttons in my desktop site. I am making changes so that it can be used in Mobile site as well. This Like and Send button is opening a pop up same as it opens in Facebook site on any page at bottom.

If I use it in same way. The pop up is too big that it cant be aligned properly as compared to the mobile device.

Please provide me the solution to get it done for mobile. I have tried doing it with writing custom css with important tag but all efforts goes in vain.

Comment: Google is your friend, first seach gave me this link.
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/06/20/bringing-like-to-mobile/

Comment: @Grumpy: Mobile(-friendly) version of a website != mobile _app_

Answer (score 0):

I believe the provider of the like button gives you options for what kind of display you want to use. You select the display, then copy and paste it into your site.

You can copy and paste the large version AND the small version into your site, then display the one you want to use based on the device size. Make sense?